# Iterating Hash/Array combination

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

You'll want to recurse through the hash, here's a recursive method: -

```
def ihash(h)

  h.each_pair do |k,v|

    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      puts "key: #{k} recursing..."
      ihash(v)
    else
      # MODIFY HERE! Look for what you want to find in the hash here
      puts "key: #{k} value: #{v}"
    end
  end
end
```

You can Then take any hash and pass it in:

```
h = {
"x" => "a",
"y" => {
    "y1" => {
        "y2" => "final"
    },
    "yy1" => "hello"
}}

ihash(h)
```

But this below Hash/Array/Hash combination is not working with the above code

```
{"status"=>"REQUEST_SUCCEEDED", "responseTime"=>27, "message"=>[], "Results"=>{"series"=>[{"seriesID"=>"LAUCN040010000000005", "data"=>[{"year"=>"2015", "period"=>"M06", "periodName"=>"June", "value"=>"18444", "footnotes"=>[{"code"=>"P", "text"=>"Preliminary."}]}, {"year"=>"2015", "period"=>"M05", "periodName"=>"May", "value"=>"18443", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2015", "period"=>"M04", "periodName"=>"April", "value"=>"18012", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2015", "period"=>"M03", "periodName"=>"March", "value"=>"17701", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2015", "period"=>"M02", "periodName"=>"February", "value"=>"17549", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2015", "period"=>"M01", "periodName"=>"January", "value"=>"17632", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M12", "periodName"=>"December", "value"=>"17631", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M11", "periodName"=>"November", "value"=>"17668", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M10", "periodName"=>"October", "value"=>"17754", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M09", "periodName"=>"September", "value"=>"18095", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M08", "periodName"=>"August", "value"=>"18219", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M07", "periodName"=>"July", "value"=>"17860", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M06", "periodName"=>"June", "value"=>"18054", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M05", "periodName"=>"May", "value"=>"18011", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M04", "periodName"=>"April", "value"=>"17737", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M03", "periodName"=>"March", "value"=>"17436", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M02", "periodName"=>"February", "value"=>"17594", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M01", "periodName"=>"January", "value"=>"17562", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2013", "period"=>"M12", "periodName"=>"December", "value"=>"17576", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2013", "period"=>"M11", "periodName"=>"November", "value"=>"17251", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2013", "period"=>"M10", "periodName"=>"October", "value"=>"17416", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2013", "period"=>"M09", "periodName"=>"September", "value"=>"18010", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2013", "period"=>"M08", "periodName"=>"August", "value"=>"18337", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2013", "period"=>"M07", "periodName"=>"July", "value"=>"17840", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2013", "period"=>"M06", "periodName"=>"June", "value"=>"18205", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2013", "period"=>"M05", "periodName"=>"May", "value"=>"18307", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2013", "period"=>"M04", "periodName"=>"April", "value"=>"17950", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2013", "period"=>"M03", "periodName"=>"March", "value"=>"17736", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2013", "period"=>"M02", "periodName"=>"February", "value"=>"17820", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2013", "period"=>"M01", "periodName"=>"January", "value"=>"17956", "footnotes"=>[{}]}]}]}}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is your question, but from the code I'd guess that you are trying to traverse nested hash and print pair unless value is Hash or Array. Your code doesn't handle arrays as a values in the hash. Here is my version:

```
def ihash(h)
  if h.is_a?(Hash)
    h.each_pair do |k, v|
      puts "key: #{k} value: #{v}" unless [Hash, Array].include?(v.class)
      puts "key: #{k} recursing..."
      ihash(v)
    end
  elsif h.is_a?(Array)
    h.each { |x| ihash(x) }
  end
end
```